# Question regarding Poisson Process

Tags: probability

Given the following information.

1. The occurrence of a loss may cause by wind, earthquake and theft.
2. Wind, earthquake and theft losses occur independently of one another.
3. Wind losses follow a Poisson Process. The expected amount of time between wind losses is 10    years.
4. Earthquake losses follow a Poisson Process. The expected amount of time between Earthquake losses is 25 years.
5. Theft losses follow a Poisson Process. The expected amount of time between Theft losses is 5 years.

Question:

The 9th loss is observed at time 31.62, what is the chance that the 3rd loss occurred before time t=8 years?

The answer is 
$$
Pr[{S_3} \le 8] = \sum\limits_{i = 3}^9 {\left( \begin{array}{l}
9\\
i
\end{array} \right)(\frac{8}{{31.62}}} {)^i}{(1 - \frac{8}{{31.62}})^{9 - i}}
$$

Could someone explain to me that how can i get this answer?
Thank you.

Comment: You can get appropriately sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that none of the information about the expected amounts of time between losses appears in the solution. This is because the information that the $9$th loss is observed at time $31.62$ years fixes the number of losses up to that time to $8$.

The answer you provide is slightly wrong, since it regards the times of $9$ losses as unknown whereas the time of the $9$th loss is known and only the times of $8$ losses are unknown. The correct answer is

$$
\Pr[S_3\le8]=\sum_{i=3}^8\binom8i\left(\frac8{31.62}\right)^i\left(1-\frac8{31.62}\right)^{8-i}\;.
$$

Given that exactly $8$ losses occurred in $31.62$ years, we can regard their times of occurrence as independently uniformly distributed over the interval. Thus each of them has an independent probability of $8/31.62$ to have occurred before $t=8$ years, so the number of such occurrences follows a binomial distribution, and the answer adds up the cases in which the number of losses before $t=8$ years was between $3$ and $8$.